Show that if $(A, B)$ is controllable then the D.T described by $x(k+1) = Ax(k-1) + Bu(k)$ with initial states $x(0), x(1)$ is also controllable
I show this statement on some lecture notes :

It is obvious that if $(A, B)$ is controllable then the D.T with initial conditions $x(0), x(1)$ described by
$$ x(k+1)= Ax(k-1) + Bu(k)$$ is also controllable

I am trying to understand why is that obvious.
My effort so far:
$$x(k) = Ax(k-2)+Bu(k-1) = A(Ax(k-4) + Bu(k-3)) + Bu(k-1) =A^2x(k-3) + ABu(k-3) + Bu(k-1)$$
$$= A^2(Ax(k-5) + Bu(k-4)) + ABu(k-3) + Bu(k-1) = A^3x(k-5) + A^2Bu(k-4) + ABu(k-3) + Bu(k-1)$$
$$= A^{k-3}x(1) + A^{k-2}Bu(0) + A^{k-3}Bu(1) + \dots + ABu(k-3) + Bu(k-1)$$
I know that if the DT was $x(k) = Ax(k-1) + Bu(k)$ then $x(k) = A^kx(0) + A^{k-1}Bu_0 + \dots Bu_{k-1}$ so should I say something like this system has $A'= A^{-3}$ and check if $(A^{-3}, B)$ is controllable?

I added an alternative approach.

The given dynamics can be written into the "standard form factor" of a state space model using
$$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
x(k) \\ x(k+1)
\end{bmatrix}}_{z(k+1)} = 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
0 & I \\ A & 0
\end{bmatrix}}_\mathcal{A}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
x(k-1) \\ x(k)
\end{bmatrix}}_{z(k)} + 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ B
\end{bmatrix}}_\mathcal{B} u(k),
$$
with $x(k)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $u(k)\in\mathbb{R}^m$ the initial variables, and $z(k)\in\mathbb{R}^{2\,n}$, $\mathcal{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{2\,n\times 2\,n}$ and $\mathcal{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{2\,n\times m}$ the reformulated variables such that the update equation indices match the "standard form factor" of a discrete time linear time invariant state space model.
Evaluating the controllability matrix of $(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$ yields
$$
\mathcal{C} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & B & 0 & A\,B & \cdots & 0 & A^{n-1} B \\ B & 0 & A\,B & 0 & \cdots & A^{n-1} B & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If the rank of the controllability matrix of $(A,B)$ is $r$, then it can be shown that the rank of the controllability matrix of $(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$ is $2\,r$. So for $r=n$ yields that the controllability matrix of $(A,B)$ and $(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$ are full rank.

can you provide some theory on "normal form factor" for discrete state space models? maybe some link?

@tonythestark I have updated my answer and what I mean with "normal/standard form factor" is the convention of index notation of the state update equation of discrete time LTI state space models, consistent with this and this.

Here is a slightly different approach based on the definition.
I presume that by controllable you mean that for any initial and final states, the system can be steered from the initial to final state in finite time.
Since $(A,B)$ is controllable we know that there is some $n$ such that for any $y_0,y_n$, there is some input $w_1,...,w_n$ such that the system $y_{k+1} = A y_k + B w_k$ is steered from $y_0$ to $y_n$.
Let $a_k = x_{2k-1}$ and $b_k = x_{2k}$, where $x_k$ is the system in the question. Note that
$a_{k+1} = A a_k + B u_{2k}$ and $b_{k+1} = A b_k + B u_{2k+1}$. In particular, we can view $a_k, b_k$ as two independent systems with the same dynamics as $y_k$.
Explicitly, if we wish to steer the system from an initial condition $(x_0,\xi_0)$ to $(x_{n},\xi_n)$, choose $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ such that it would steer the $y_k$ system from
$x_{0}$ to $x_{n}$ and $\beta_1,...,\beta_n$ such that it would steer the $y_k$ system from
$\xi_{0}$ to $\xi_{n}$.
Then the input $u$ given by $\alpha_1,\beta_1,...,\alpha_n,\beta_n$ will steer the system from $(x_0,\xi_0)$ to $(x_{n},\xi_n)$ in $2n$ steps.

This answer is more elegant because it would also translate better for even larger delays in the state.

@KwinvanderVeen I think they end up being the same thing. I like the above mainly because  I think the Krylov subspace approach 'hides' the intuition.
